# Error when using HTML/JS code to let users record video using webcam

Tags: javascript, html, video

This is the code I used in the index page. I want to let users record a video using their webcam. When I run the app, all I see is space where the video recorder is supposed to be and the stop button. When I do "inspect source" and hover over the area where the recorder is supposed to be, it gets highlighter, that means its their, I just cant see it. Also there is an error shown in the inspect source code which is shown and the code is shown below that.[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    navigator.getUserMedia = 
        navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    var video = document.querySelector('video');
    var cameraStream = '';
    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia(
            {audio: true, video: true}
            function(stream)
            {
                cameraStream = Stream;
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
            }
            function()
            {
                document.writeln("problem")
            }
        );
    }
    else
    {
        document.writeln("not support");
    }
    document.querySelector('#stopbt').addEventListener(
        'click',
        function(e)
        {
            video.src="";
            cameraStream.stop();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: You need a comma after the object on line 64 and after the first callback function in the arguments list.

Comment: Also note that `navigator.getUserMedia` API is deprecated, you should be using [`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) one, and using `URL.createObjectURL(mediaStream)` is a very bad idea, moreover when you don't seem to revoke this blobURI : it will stuck your hardware in `active` mode. Instead, use `videoElement.srcObject = mediaStream`

Comment: @WillReese Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kaiido Hello! Thanks for your feedback. Since I copied this code from a tutorial, I am not entirely sure what you mean by the second part of your answer. I willreplace navigator.getUserMedia with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia, but would you please be able to explain the next part a little bit more? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are currently doing `video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream)`. This is bad practice, and is on the way to be deprecated by the way. When you do so, the browser will create an memory access to your hardware (camera or microphone), which won't be released before an hard refresh of the page, or browser being killed. The correct way to do it is to use your video element's `srcObject` property, which will accept mediaStreams without locking the hardware : `video.srcObject = stream`;

Comment: @Kaiido Hey buddy, I changed the code. Does it look good? Still I only see blank space with stop button. I am adding this code on the index.html.erb page. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `,` in between the `}` and `{` (in between lines 64 and 65)

**Sorry not a semicolon**

Try refreshing because the screenshot has an error but it is different code than the code in the question. The code in the question should work because the user friendly description of the error is the correct error that would show in what the code is.

Comment: Thanks man. I changed it. I'm using this now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146379/letting-users-use-their-webcam-to-record-video